# 4GB SQL Database - Server Upgrade & Performance

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL-Server database that is rapidly approaching the 4Gb limitation in SQL Server 2005 Express.

I know that we have the option of upgrading to SQL 2008R2 Express to resolve the database restriction, but before doing so, I am trying to explore the possibility of the other restrictions imposed - namely the 1GB RAM per database, that may make it worthwhile to upgrade to SQL Workstation or Standard instead.

Background: We have a small accountancy practice, 1 Peer Server running WinXP Pro, but due to software terminating support for WindowsXP, is due to be upgraded this month. The Server runs Sage50 (www.sage.co.uk) and IRIS Accounting (www.iris.co.uk), and network shares for staff data.

We have 9 Win7 client PCs, accessing the SQL Server instance for IRIS on the server, over the 1000mb/s network.

Question 1. The Server has 8GB of ram, If I upgraded the Server to SQL Workstation or Standard, am I likely to see a performance benefit as the express edition has a 1GB Ram limitation?

Question 2. Will SQL for instance load more of the database into RAM, or possibly the whole database if enough RAM was available?

Best Regards...

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express has updated that limit to 10 GB .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Yes, you may well see a performance increase.  SQL Server will take up as much RAM as possible in order to be as performant as it can be.

Question 2: I doubt that SQL will load your *whole* database into RAM.  SQL will load execution plans and store dirty data in the RAM rather than load a whole database into memory.

For more information, read this article about [Buffer Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337525.aspx).

> The primary purpose of a SQL Server database is to store and retrieve
>   data, so intensive disk I/O is a core characteristic of the Database
>   Engine. And because disk I/O operations can consume many resources and
>   take a relatively long time to finish, SQL Server focuses on making
>   I/O highly efficient. Buffer management is a key component in
>   achieving this efficiency. The buffer management component consists of
>   two mechanisms: the buffer manager to access and update database
>   pages, and the buffer cache (also called the buffer pool), to reduce
>   database file I/O.

Comment: Thank you very much, interesting read, albeit a little technical lol